# Finding number of integer partitions

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, combinatorics

I am trying to find number of integer partitions of given n - number. If I have `n == 4`, the answer should be 5 because:

1. \$4 = 1+1+1+1\$
2. \$4 = 2+1+1\$
3. \$4 = 3+1\$
4. \$4 = 2+2\$
5. \$4 = 4\$

My code works properly but the matter is that it counts big numbers for a very long time. I have no idea how to optimize my code. Maybe you can help me to make it faster?

```
def get_answer(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for p in get_answer(n-1):
        yield [1] + p
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[1] > p[0]):
            yield [p[0] + 1] + p[1:]
number_of_partitions=lambda n:sum(1 for _ in get_answer(n))
```

Comment: This will be of combinatorial complexity any way you do it - so I think we need a dynamic programming / memoization approach here.

Comment: Use a concise [generating function approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10035752/1190388)

Comment: @hjpotter92 I tried them all. Only accel_asc is a bit faster but it requires much more memory. That's why it will not do for me.

Comment: @Nikita.K Are there any restrictions to what you can use? It seems like `accel_asc` is your best option in terms of speed. Otherwise, you're stuck with your funciton. In this case, I would first try a different implementation such as [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) or maybe augment Python a bit with [Cython](http://cython.org/). After that I would just use another language honestly.

Comment: @Dair Actually this task is from Codewars. So, I can't use any implementations. Also, Python is the only language I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly more efficient dynamic programming approach means you only need `O(n)` space:

```
def partitions(n):
    parts = [1]+[0]*n
    for t in range(1, n+1):
        for i, x in enumerate(range(t, n+1)):
            parts[x] += parts[i]
    return parts[n]

In []:
partitions(50)

Out[]:
204226
```

Note: this is trivial to extend to the coin change problem (the number of ways you can make change with certain coins: [Ways to make change for a dollar](https://www.maa.org/frank-morgans-math-chat-293-ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar)), by restricted the values in the outer loop, e.g.:

```
def coin_change(n, coins):
    parts = [1]+[0]*n
    for c in coins:
        for i, x in enumerate(range(c, n+1)):
            parts[x] += parts[i]
    return parts[n]

In []:
coin_change(100, {1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100})

Out[]:
293
```

Answer (score 2):

> My code works properly but the matter is that it counts big numbers
>   for a very long time. I have no idea how to optimize my code. Maybe
>   you can help me to make it faster?
>
> ```
> ...
> number_of_partitions=lambda n:sum(1 for _ in get_answer(n))
> ```

Don't count. Calculate.

The Wikipedia article on [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) gives the Hardy-Ramanujan estimate \$P(n) = \Theta(n^{-1} e^{k \sqrt n})\$ with \$k=\pi \sqrt\frac23\$. Since your code finds the partitions to count them, and since the "average" partition has a lot of \$1\$s, your running time is \$\Omega(e^{k \sqrt n})\$.

The Wikipedia article also gives a number of recurrence relations, including one which uses generalised pentagonal numbers (giving a running time of \$\Theta(n^{1.5})\$), and another which uses the sum of divisors function (giving a running time of \$\Theta(n^2)\$ if you pre-calculate the sum of divisors using e.g. the sieve of Eratosphenes). An alternative quadratic approach (which you could find by following the [Mathworld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) from Wikipedia) uses the auxiliary function \$P(n,k)\$ for the number of partitions of \$n\$ into parts of which the largest is exactly \$k\$ and the recurrence \$P(n,k)=P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-k,k)\$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect task to solve with dynamic programming. Using a C++-script found [here](https://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/) and some additional optimization, I created this script:

```
num = 100
scores = [[int(j==0 and i>0) for i in range(num)] for j in range(num)]
max_part = num-1
calculated = [1]

def get_combinations(n, x = max_part):
    for i in range(calculated[0], n+1):
        for j in range(1, x+1):
            if (i-j<0):
                scores[i][j] = scores[i][j-1]
                continue
            scores[i][j] = scores[i][j-1] + scores[i-j][j];
    calculated[0] = n
    return scores[n][x]

print(get_combinations(50))
```

This script outputs 204226, and additionally its output is identical for any input value (I only tested up to 65, because the function in your question ran slowly after that).

The major drawback of the dynamic solution is that it is space inefficient. To calculate `get_combinations(n)`, one must use `O(n^2)` memory to store the `scores`-array. However, it performs much better for large values of `n`. And an additional feature (my addition to the C++-script) is that if you run the function multiple times, it doesn't recalculate any numbers.

Thus, if `get_combinations(5)` has been calculated, then a subsequent call to `get_combinations(2)` only requires an array lookup, and a subsequent call to `get_combinations(10)` is faster.

This function should work without issues for any `n` under 1000 (for input larger than 100 the variable `num` needs to be adjusted), and is 400 times faster for `n = 65` on my machine in the worst case. Sequentially calculating all values between 1 and 1000 runs in <0.5s.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: FWIW this seems like justification that it is an improvement over the original: "_However, it performs much better for large values of `n`. And an additional feature (my addition to the C++-script) is that if you run the function multiple times, it doesn't recalculate any numbers._"

Comment: @TobySpeight The IO rule started simply by 200_success as: "[Would this answer constitute a reasonable checkin log message?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479)" with a number of real world examples. Please note the latest version of the rule is: "[the minimum expectation of an insightful observation ... should be to say what parameter(s) it improves](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9309)". To my eyes the section SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ quoted clearly describes an improved parameter and would be a more than valid checkin message. Hence constitutes an IO.

Comment: It's probably better to start with the observation at the beginning of the answer, and the code that illustrates the improvement afterwards.  The actual review can easily be obscured by hiding it in the middle like this!